# Modify many rows in a mysql database at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, database, str-replace

I have a database with prices from lots of different products. They're all in this format: 
£25,000.

What I want is the following: 25000.

I figured I must use a foreach loop and use str_replace, but I can't seem to find a way to delete the pound sign and the comma.

I also have a few rows where the prices are missing, they're in the database as following:  £00

Again, I want to delete the pound sign. So that must be a different loop I guess?

Could you explain how it must be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$new_array = str_replace(array("£",","),array("",""),$old_array);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will remove comma and `£` (if present), in all your rows at once

```
update your_table
set your_column = replace(replace(your_column, '£', ''), ',', '')
```